# When adding libs in gradle getting Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

[image: Errors]
[image: Here is my gradle dependencies]

> Errors are related to libs I have add even same libs working with other project.

- implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4'
- implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:X.X.X'

Comment: Perhaps your other project has a repository that does have those artifacts

Answer (score 0):

By having these repositories:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

you could get these libs, but not the latest version since they are not available on maven repo:

```
implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.0'
implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablecheckrecyclerview:0.3'
```

You need to add [PageIndicatorView](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView) manually to your project because it is hosted on `jcenter` which no longer works on Android Studio.

You may manually add the latest version of expandablerecyclerview to your project or ask the owner to update it on the maven repo.